# Creepy Ancient Lady in the Bathtub in Doctor Sleep

Tags: character, doctor-sleep

Who is the Creepy old lady in Doctor Sleep, who keeps appearing in the movie?

She is always in the Bathtub, why are the actors in the movie visiting this character?
a) Jack in the movie Shining sees this old lady step out of the bathtub.
b) Danny in Doctor Sleep visits her in the bathroom at the beginning of the movie
c) Abra in Doctor Sleep visits her in the bathroom at the end of the movie

We later see this old ancient lady feeding off Rose the hat at the Hotel when Danny lures Rose to the other ghosts at the hotel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I haven't seen Doctor Sleep; it seems clear from your description that this is a reference to a [well-known scene in Stephen King's *The Shining*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZ6hgh8kd0A) (warning: graphic content).

Comment: I added the code markup to prevent the video from loading inline; as the thumbnail itself is graphic. Feel free to edit if there's a better way to prevent this while leaving the url as a link.

Comment: I made the link...into a link.

Comment: I watched the movie again, So to answer my second part of the question, The characters are visiting her in the bathtub to trap those ghosts in a box in their mind.